# How to handle replacing views android

Tags: android, listview, android-menu

I have a `MainActivity` class which extends `SlidingMenu`.

When the user clicks in the sliding menu on an item, I would like to reload the `View`(different layout and content) of `MainActivity`.

In most cases the new `View` would consiste of a `ListView` with customs cells.

Is it possible to do this when I create a `MyListViewActivity` inside `MainActivity`? Or does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it (it all depends on your implementation) is just to use `setContentView(R.layout.new_layout)` on button click, which will inflate the other layout inside the same activity, replacing the old layout. BUT then be careful that all menus/action bars still get inflated, and that you don't reference any widgets which exist on the old layout.

If you want to have just a small section appear inside of your main layout, in your xml you could have something like:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/small_layout_1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/small_layout_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

then on the button press you find the reference to small_layout_1, make visibility=gone, find small_layout_2 and make visibility=visible, which will achieve the same behaviour I think you're looking for

Comment: Out of interest, which method did you end up going for in the end?